# ng-Click not working with {{$index}} inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this seems like a simple problem but it has taken hours of mine .

I've the following code.

```
            <div class="row grid" id="draftRow{{$index}}" ng-repeat="draft in drafts">
            <div class="col-md-7 cell" ng-bind="draft.getTitle()"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 cell center" ng-bind="draft.getUserName()"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 cell center" ng-bind="draft.getDate()"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1 cell center" >
                <span class="gridbutton" ng-click="editPost(draft.getPostID())">edit</span>
                |
                <span class="gridbutton" ng-click="deletePost(draft.getPostID(),'{{$index}}')">delete</span>
            </div>
            </div>
```

The deletePost function is not being called onclick although I can see `deletePost(draft.getPostID(),'0')` written on browser inspect element. What is the problem here can anyone point out ? If I remove the second parameter of the deletePost function everything runs fine .

I've also tried `$parent.$index` , that calls the function but doesn't output the `rowIndex` on inspect element.

Comment: Have you tried using just `deletePost(draft.getPostID(), $index)`? - I do not see why you want to use `{{$index}}` instead of just the variable itself...

Comment: yup worked :D thanks , I think I should take a break :p

Comment: If you don't mind I will post it as an "answer" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment: instead of using `{{...}}` for interpretation, just use the variable itself: `deletePost(draft.getPostID(), $index)`